# Empty array when index is end of array

Tags: ruby

> Negative indices count backward from the end of the array (-1 is the
>   last element). For start and range cases the starting index is just
>   before an element. Additionally, an empty array is returned when the
>   starting index for an element range is at the end of the array.
>
> Returns nil if the index (or starting index) are out of range.

Why does

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4]
a[4] #=> 4
a[4,0] #=> [] - length is 0, so empty array is returned

a[5] #=> nil - makes sense since it is out of range
a[5,0] #=> [] - why is this empty?
a[6,0] #=> nil - but this is nil?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put in {ix} for the positions instead of commas.

```
a = [{ix0}0{ix1}1{ix2}2{ix3}3{ix4}4{ix5}]
```

a[5,0] means go to 5 {ix5} and take 0 elements. That is just an empty array.

{ix6} is not a valid starting positions, thus nil.